# RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch. I'm trying to  implement a custom loss function by computing the absolute and relative distance and concatenating them.

```
def distance(p1, p2,labels):
        """
        Returns the distance between the point sets p1 and p2
        p1 = m by d matrix containing a set of points
        p2 = m by d matrix containing a different set of points

        returns: an m-length vector containing the  distance from each point in
            p1 to the corresponding point in p2
        """
        if not np.all(p1.shape == p2.shape):
            raise ValueError("p1 and p2 must be the same shape.")
        d = p1.shape[1]

        features = np.zeros(dtype=np.float32, shape=(p1.shape[0], d * 2))
        features[:, :d] = np.abs(p1 - p2)
        features[:, d:] = (p1 + p2) / 2

        return  features
```

The problem appears when I try to run it and  I get the following error:

File "... line 34, in distance

```
features[:, :d] = np.abs(p1 - p2)
```

File "...\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

File "...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 266, in abs
    x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")

File "...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1087, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)

`RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead.`

Comment: Are you mixing tensorflow and pytorch?

Comment: I'm new to pytorch if anything you can correct me

Comment: Pytorch and Tensorflow are two completely different things. They cannot be mixed. You must search through Pytorch's help and documentation for the functions you want. It's very very similar to Tensorflow's eager mode with custom training loops, and the models are created similarly to the new keras "subclassing" style. It will not be very hard to learn, but if you use PyTorch, you can use only PyTorch.

Comment: so i do i correct this problem... can you assist me?

Comment: Use only pytorch functions, don't use numpy functions and don't use tensorflow functions.

Comment: See, for instance `torch.abs` here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what is going wrong. You need to convert first the pytorch tensor into a numpy array. You can do that using .detach().numpy()

So inside your function you can put:

```
def distance(p1, p2, labels):
    p1 = p1.detach().numpy()
    p2 = p2.detach().numpy()
    labels = labels.detach().numpy()
```

Even though be aware that tensor are meant to speed up calculations, converting them into array means to increase computation time. So looking at pytorch functions as suggested in the comments is definitely the best approach to follow.

Comment: Also, it's important to keep all torch for backpropagation.

Comment: Absolutely. But as long as you convert everything inside a function everything is fine. I do it myself sometimes when I want to inspect the results with customise score metrics.

Comment: Really? How will it know the derivatives of numpy operations?

Comment: Ok you're right, I just read the name of function 'distance' and missed that the purpose is to make a loss function. In that case you need tensors of course.

Comment: (Semi)-related to your comments: when calculating the metrics, is there a reason one would want to use numpy operations and not torch operations? This is how they do it in Andrew Ng's tutorial (converting to numpy). I just asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179954/should-a-data-batch-be-moved-to-cpu-and-converted-from-torch-tensor-to-a-numpy) about this, I would appreciate any insights you can provide.